# Is there a benefit/penalty in record modification?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, ocaml

In a functional program I have an API that provides functions on complex state implemented as a record:

```
let remove_number nr {counter ; numbers ; foo } = {counter ; numbers = IntSet.remove nr numbers ; foo}
let add_fresh {counter ; numbers ; foo } = { counter = counter + 1 ; numbers = IntSet.add counter numbers ; foo }
```

I know, I can use the simplified record modification syntax like this:

```
let remove_number nr state = { state with numbers = IntSet.remove nr numbers }
```

When the record type grows, the latter style is actually more readable. Hence, I will probably use it anyway. But out of curiosity, I wonder, whether it also allows the compiler to detect possible memory reusage more easily (my application is written in a monadic style, so there will usually only be one record that is passed along, hence an optimizing compiler could remove all allocations but one and do in-place-mutation instead). In my limited view, the `with`-syntax gives a good heuristic for places to apply such optimization, but is that true?

- Does OCaml even optimize (unneeded) record allocations?
- Is the record modification syntax lowered before any optimizations apply?
- And finally, is there any pattern recognition implemented in the ocaml
  compiler, that tells it that there is a "cheap" way to create one
  record expression by modifying a "dead" value in place (and how is
  that optimization usually called)?

Answer (score 3):

The two versions of `remove_number` that you give are equivalent. The `{ expr with ... }` notation doesn't modify a record. It creates a new record.

Record modification looks like this:

```
let remove_number nr rec = rec.numbers <- IntSet.remove nr rec.numbers
```

I don't think OCaml does the sort of optimization you describe. The plan with OCaml is to generate code that's close to what you write.

Comment: hopefully it will do one day!

Comment: I am aware about the distinction between mutable modifications and record-expressions, as you should have seen in the question ;). So basically you say there is no allocation-optimization at all in OCaml? Do you have a source for that? This would make a perfectly acceptable answer then.